# ListView set visible two buttons on long click

Tags: android, listview

I have problem with ListView and ArrayAdapter. I want to show delete button on long press on ListView item. Problem is that I get more than once button showed on long click (depends of how many item i see on display. If I'm in portrait mode, I see, for example first 10 of 15, and when I press long on item at position 3, i will see two buttons, at position 3 and at position 13. If I'm at landscape mode, I see first 4 of 15 items, and when I press long at 2, I will see buttons at position 2, 6, 10, 14.). But, when I press other buttons, I still delete original item (item that long pressed). Here is example of my code.

**TicketListAdapter**

```
public class TicketListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ticket> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
TabFragmentAdapter tabMenager;
List<Ticket> data = null;

public TicketListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Ticket> objects, TabFragmentAdapter tabMenager) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = objects;
    this.tabMenager = tabMenager;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    TicketHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new TicketHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtGain = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteTicketButton);
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new DeleteTicketAction((Activity) context, getItemId(position), tabMenager, null, null));
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (TicketHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Ticket ticket = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(ticket.ticketName);
    holder.txtGain.setText("Possible gain: " + ticket.possibleGain);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(StatusHelper.getStatusIconType(ticket.status.status, context));

    return row;
}

static class TicketHolder {
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtGain;
    Button btnDelete;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return data.get(position).getId();
}
```

**list_ticket_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/checkbox_marked_circle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/deleteTicketButton"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_forever"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ListFragment**

```
public class AllTicketsFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, FragmentUpdateInterface {

TicketListAdapter arrayAdapter;
TabFragmentAdapter tabMenager;

public AllTicketsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public AllTicketsFragment(TabFragmentAdapter tabManager) {
    this.tabMenager = tabManager;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    List<Ticket> tickets = null;
    try {
        tickets = new GetTicketFromDBTask(getActivity()).execute("all").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    arrayAdapter = new TicketListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_ticket_view, tickets, tabMenager);
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    getListView().addFooterView(getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.list_footer_view, null), null, false);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TicketDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Button deleteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteTicketButton);
    if (deleteButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: try to declare the deleteButton in the onCreateView and not in the longClick method

Comment: Hi, tnx for your quick response, but that doesn't fixed my problem. deleteButton is always null outside this longClick method.